# Xamarin authentication using JWT

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth, cross-platform, jwt

I have begun development of my first Xamarin cross-platform application for Android and iOS (not using Xamarin Forms). The application will require the user to login using a REST API and stay authenticated. I've looked into Xamarin.Auth but can't find any method of using that without OAuth.

The backend is setup to provide a JWT and was hoping that could be used for the authentication in a similar way to how a website would use JWT for authentication.

My approach for this would be:

- Use WebClient to send the login credentials to the API
- API sends back the JWT
- Xamarin stores the JWT on the device
- Each API call sends the JWT along with it
- API checks if the JWT is valid

Is this a secure method of authentication? What would be the best way to store the JWT in the application?

P.S. the main reason I am not using OAuth is because I have not setup (and not entirely sure how to) the backend for OAuth authentication.

Thanks.

Comment: Just my 5 cents: It's essential that you use a SSL/TLS connection. If someone is able to intercept your JWT-Token your users gonna have a bad time!

Comment: @StefanWanitzek I completely forgot about securing the token. I'll look into SSL certificates. Thanks!

Comment: My 2cents, each platform has secure storage (iOS KeyChain, Android KeyStore, ...) and there are PCL-based wrappers available so you can do this from `Xamarin.Forms` if needed so there is no need to roll-your-own. Also the pre-release (5.0.0-rc2-305061149) of  System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" works in PCL profile 78 so you can look at that if you need to implement a JWToken Serializer and Deserializer... I went briefly down this path till the client OK'd an oauth2 replacement. And of course like @StefanWanitzek said, use a secure connection.

Comment: @SushiHangover I thought Xamarin.Forms was for UI development? I'm aware of storing the token in the KeyChain/KeyStore using the  Xamarin.Auth Account object, but not entirely sure how to use it with the WebClient (only examples I can find involve OAuth). I'll probably attempt setting up OAuth2 for the system but until then I'll look into System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt. Thank you :)

Comment: @SubhanUr-Rehman Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Forms are for UI development, depending upon how your structure your solution for code sharing, usage of libraries that support PCL profiles like 78, 111, etc.. allow you to reference those libraries between the various project types vs using shared-code projects and using conditional defines around platform-dependent code... your choice of how you do it, just pointing that those libraries support those PCL profiles...

Comment: @SushiHangover Okay that makes sense. My solution is a PCL for code sharing and Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android for the UIs and platform specific code

Comment: @SushiHangover Now there's a project called `Xamarin.Essentials` in which it contains `SecureStorage`.